# Conditional Independence and d separation

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

I am reading Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher M. Bishop.
I am unable to proof one of the steps.
The question is of Bayesian Belief networks: Head to Tail Case

[image: 3 node graph to show conditional independence] 
$$ P(a,b,c) = P(a) * P (c|a)* P(b|c) $$

Suppose that none of the variables are observed. We can test to
see if a and b are independent by marginalizing over c to give

$$ P(a,b) = P(a) * \sum_{c} P(c|a)* P(b|c) $$

Now the next step which I am unable to understand how it got here:

$$ P(a,b) = P(a) * P(b|a) $$

Comment: By definition: $P(b\mid a)=P(a,b)/P(a)$

Comment: The question is to prove $P(b|a) = \sum_c P(c|a) * P(b|c)$

Comment: You have established *from the network* that $~P(a,b) = P(a)\cdot \sum_c P(c\mid a)\cdot P(b\mid c)~$, and *by definition* we know that $~P(a,b) = P(a)\cdot P(b\mid a)~$, therefore *we may conclude* that $~P(b\mid a)=\sum_c P(c\mid a)\cdot P(b\mid c)~$. @NofelYaseen

Comment: Thank you. If possible, please post an answer using diagrams to develop the intuition behind this.